# Git merge doesn't get files that discarded before

Tags: git

When I tried to `merge` (5 files) dev to test, I `discard`ed some files (2 files) and `commit`ed others (3 files). After a while I needed to merge my discarded two files to test branch but discarded files didn't appear in `working tree`. Is there a bug here or did i do something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you`add` the deletion of the files? You use the word `discard` which is unclear in git terminology. Can you specify if/when you deleted the files / added the deletion. Showing the commands you used would be a plus. (As a sidenote about formatting, use code extracts (with backticks) for *actual code extracts*, or even command names, but not for general terms. `discard` is not code, nor is `working tree`)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by discard here? Also, "after a wile I needed to merge my discarded files", and then what did you do here?

Comment: Do note that there is no such thing as a partial merge. When you merge two branches, **those two branches are now merged**. If you discarded some changes one branch introduced, git will not consider that as "postponed until later", it will assume those changes are not needed. If you later try to merge the source branch again, there will be no more changes because the branch has already been merged.

Comment: Firstly, I used `discard` in git terminology discard. I discarded files. @LasseVågsætherKarlsen got me right. I exactly tried to postpone merge for some files but i didn't work out. Is there any work-around for this issue?

Comment: Other than manually reintroducing the changes you discarded, I don't believe there is. You *might* be able to muck around with a revert command and get some help, but I'm not sure it would be easier.

Comment: You can use the syntax `git checkout <sha1> -- <file>` to get the files back in their pre-merge state in your sandbox, and then commit the results. This will give you a regular commit instead of a merge, but as @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, that's your only option now.

Answer (score 1):

## Part 1

I have created the following test repo to replicate what I think is your scenario:

```bash
mkdir /tmp/test
cd /tmp/test
git init
touch .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m .gitignore
touch file{1,2,3,4,5}
git add file{1,2,3,4,5}
git commit -m "Create files"
git checkout -b feature1
for i in file{1,2,3,4,5}; do echo "This is $i" >> $i; done
git add .
git commit -m "Update files"
git checkout main 
for i in file{1,2,3,4,5}; do echo "This is line 1" >> $i; done
git add .
git commit -m "Add line 1"
git merge feature1
```

So at this point we have merge conflicts on all five files.

I resolving them by keeping "This is line 1" as line 1 and the line "This is file" as line two.

```bash
vi file*
git add .
```

So at this point all conflicts are resolved for all files, however let's discard file1 and file2 back to `main` content and complete the merge:

```bash
git reset file1 file2
git checkout file1 file2
git commit
git tag merge-commit-2-of-5
```

---

## Part 2

So your wish is to merge `feature1` into `main` once more to merge the two missing files. This can be done as follows:

1. Create a new branch from right before the merge is done.

```bash
git checkout -b before-merge merge-commit-2-of-5^   # the "^" here indicates (first) parent
```

2. Bring in all changes from the merge but only the content and no "meta information" like merge parents.

```bash
git diff HEAD merge-commit-2-of-5 | git apply -
git commit -am "Existing merge changes" -m "Generated with: git diff HEAD merge-commit-2-of-5 | git apply -"
```

3. At this point you have a branch with the merge changes for file{3,4,5} present but without it being recorded as a merge, which is the key to be able to merge `feature1` again.

```bash
git merge feature1
# file3, file4, and file5 also ends up as being conflicted, but since their content is
# already ok, reset those
git reset file{3,4,5}
git checkout file{3,4,5}
vi file1 file2   # resolve conflicts normally
git add file1 file2
git commit -m "Merge of the last two files"
```

At this point the last commit is exactly what you asked for, *a postponed merge for some files*. You can then either cherry-pick that commit or merge the `before-merge` branch into `main`.